# Making subarrays from an array algorithm javascript

Tags: javascript

Given an array `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7]`.

How do i make subarrays `[2, 2, 2] , [3, 3] , [5, 5, 5], [7]` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this guide on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, your question does not show research effort as you do not show any code that you have written.

Comment: Is there some sort of pattern in the types/sizes of "subarrays" you are seeking to generate?

Comment: The array consists of prime numbers. I want an array for each prime number. For example [2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 11] ---> [2, 2] , [3] , [5, 5] , [7] , [11, 11].